# Show image from MSSQL via php

Tags: php, sql-server

I need to show images that stored at MSSQL DB;

First i am getting image;

```
$query=sqlsrv_query($conn,"SELECT Picture FROM dbo.PList WHERE ID='$_GET[id]' AND Section='$_SESSION[divID]'");
$photo=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
$photo=$photo["Picture"];
```

Then, if i use this code, it works:

```
$mime = "image/jpeg";
$b64Src = "data:".$mime.";base64," . base64_encode($photo);         
echo '<img src="'.$b64Src.'" alt="" />';
```

But, i when i am trying to use this:

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
print($photo);
```

Browser says, that there is an error.
How to show image, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: "Browser says, that there is an error." could you share that error with us?

Comment: Original error is in russian, so i translated: Image "http://10.40.2.122/photo.php?id=4" cant be showen, because it contains errors

Comment: @Yan good idea to translate then :)

Comment: Somebody has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't You use

`echo base64_decode($photo)` 
insted of print ?